# Oracle adf table clicktoEdit multiple rowselection bug?

Tags: oracle-adf, multipleselection, clicktoedit

We have a af:table with following properties:

- rowSelection="multiple"
- editingMode ="clickToEdit"

If you click on a row to select it, then scroll down so new data is being fetched, then press shift and click on an other row (to select multiple rows), only the last row is selected.
Did anybody have the same problem? How can it be fixed?

Version: 11.1.1.6.0

My table def:

```
<af:table 
    value="#{bindings.EmployeesView.collectionModel}" 
    var="row" 
    rows="#{bindings.EmployeesView.rangeSize}" 
    emptyText="#{bindings.EmployeesView.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}" 
    fetchSize="#{bindings.EmployeesView.rangeSize}" 
    rowBandingInterval="0" 
    filterModel="#{bindings.EmployeesViewQuery.queryDescriptor}" 
    queryListener="#{bindings.EmployeesViewQuery.processQuery}" 
    filterVisible="false" 
    varStatus="vs" 
    rowSelection="multiple" 
    id="t3" 
    editingMode="clickToEdit" 
    partialTriggers=":::pcDep:tDep" 
    contentDelivery="immediate" 
    summary="Employees table">
```

Comment: Does your use case really state that you need to be able to edit multiple records at once?

Comment: No it doesn't. But you should be able to select multiple records at once. To delete them, for example. Or to copy them.

Comment: Yes of course. But when you use editingMode, you will do a setCurrentRow every time you click a record. So combining multiple row selection and click to edit won't work (well, the multiple row selection won't).

Comment: Strange thing is it works well, except for the case where you want to select too much lines (when you go 'out of range')